# useReducer is not updating but is adding states to the wrong place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use a reducer to manage the states of onboarding sign up components I've made. But I'm having trouble dispatching the information. I have my reducer in the parent component and I use context to pass the state and dispatch to the sign up components. The states are updated fine in the first component with dispatch but when I dispatch from the second component the information is added to the first components object in the state instead of updating it's own object. I'm using React Native but I've typed a react example of this in code sandbox since it's a few pages long and they don't have a react native option.

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-voice-9w4r3g?file=/src/SignUp.tsx

An example of the result:

This is what I'm expecting

```
{
  user: {},
  business: {},
  index: 0,
  termsAgreement: false
}
```

This is how it comes out

```
{
  user: {
    business: {} <-- updated
  },
  index: 0,
  termsAgreement: false,
  business: {} <-- not updated
}
```

Code

```
export const SignUp = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    BusinessSignUpReducer,
    BusinessInitialState
  );

  const index = useMemo(() => {
    switch (state.index) {
      case 1:
        return <BusinessForm />;

      case 2:
        return <EndForm />;

      case 0:
      default:
        return <UserForm />;
    }
  }, [state.index]);

  return (
    <SignUpBusinessContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {index}
    </SignUpBusinessContext.Provider>
  );
};


export const BusinessSignUpReducer = (
  state: SignUpStore,
  action: SignUpBusinessActions
): SignUpStore => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SignUpActionType.ACCEPT_TERMS:
      return { ...state, termsAgreement: action.payload };
    case SignUpActionType.SET_INDEX:
      return { ...state, index: action.payload };
    case SignUpActionType.UPDATE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: { ...state.user, ...action.payload }
      };
    case SignUpBusinessActionType.UPDATE_BUSINESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        business: { ...state.business, ...action.payload }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export enum SignUpBusinessActionType {
  UPDATE_BUSINESS
}

interface UpdateBusiness {
  type: SignUpBusinessActionType.UPDATE_BUSINESS;
  payload: BusinessProps;
}

export const updateBusiness = (business: any): UpdateBusiness => ({
  type: SignUpBusinessActionType.UPDATE_BUSINESS,
  payload: business
});

export type SignUpBusinessActions =
  | ReturnType<typeof updateBusiness>
  | UserActions;



export enum SignUpActionType {
  UPDATE_USER,
  ACCEPT_TERMS,
  SET_INDEX
}

interface AcceptTerms {
  type: SignUpActionType.ACCEPT_TERMS;
  payload: boolean;
}

interface SetIndex {
  type: SignUpActionType.SET_INDEX;
  payload: number;
}

interface UpdateUser {
  type: SignUpActionType.UPDATE_USER;
  payload: UserProps;
}

export const setIndex = (index: number): SetIndex => ({
  type: SignUpActionType.SET_INDEX,
  payload: index
});

export const acceptTerms = (value: boolean): AcceptTerms => ({
  type: SignUpActionType.ACCEPT_TERMS,
  payload: value
});

export const updateUser = (user: any): UpdateUser => ({
  type: SignUpActionType.UPDATE_USER,
  payload: user
});

export type UserActions =
  | ReturnType<typeof acceptTerms>
  | ReturnType<typeof setIndex>
  | ReturnType<typeof updateUser>;


export type UserProps = {
  user: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
  };
  termsAgreement: boolean;
  index: number;
};

export const UserInitalState: UserProps = {
  user: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  },
  termsAgreement: false,
  index: 0
};

export interface BusinessStateProps extends UserProps {
  business: BusinessProps;
}

export interface BusinessProps {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  location: {
    street1: string;
    street2: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zipcode: string;
  };
}

export const BusinessInitialState = {
  ...UserInitalState,
  business: {
    name: "",
    description: "",
    location: {
      street1: "",
      street2: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zipcode: ""
    }
  }
};

export type SignUpStore = typeof UserInitalState & typeof BusinessInitialState;


export const SignUpBusinessContext = createContext<{
  state: BusinessStateProps;
  dispatch: Dispatch<SignUpBusinessActions>;
}>({ state: BusinessInitialState, dispatch: () => undefined });
```

I'm not use to reducers so it's probably a slip up but I cannot find where the problem is when comparing my code to others and examples.

Comment: Post the relevant but minimal set of code to reproduce the problem *here* as formatted text and not on external sites. External sites may go down or the content may change or be deleted, rendering the question unusable.

Comment: Oh okay I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

```
export enum SignUpBusinessActionType {
  UPDATE_BUSINESS
}

export enum SignUpActionType {
  UPDATE_USER,
  ACCEPT_TERMS,
  SET_INDEX
}
```

I didn't include values for my enum so it was using the default values which are numbers. Since UPDATE_USER and UPDATE_BUSINESS are both first the default value for both is 0. So when the action got to my reducer and hit UPDATE_USER instead of rejecting the value and moving on, it was accepted since UPDATE_USER is looking for 0 but UPDATE_BUSINESS is also looking for 0 but is never reached because UPDATE_USER has already been returned.